# Python - SQL Server AWS Lambda Integration

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

my app does some http request and insert the result into sql server db on daily basis. sql server is on amazon's rds service, i use default-vpc settings.

When i try to use it in aws lambda (packaged as it defined on the aws-lambda documentation),  it gives following error:

> module initialization error: 'ODBC Library is not found. Is
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?'

I use pypyodbc as python mssql module.

Do i need to setup odbc library manually?

Attached role includes the policiy:

- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

Edit: i tried to use ceodbc and pyodbc, unable to find module "" error raised. (installed in virtualenv with ceodbc whl file, pyodbc with pip)
NOTE: those two has .pyd file extensions in root level, since they are also in the site-packages folder. I guess amazon lambda doesn't include pyd file while executing.

Edit2: followed these steps, got same error. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-rds-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a VPC problem, but more a problem of package that is not in the lambda.

In python, the best way is to install your packages in your lambda folder before compressing all in the .zip : 
`$ pip install YOUR_MODULE -t YOUR_LAMBDA_FOLDER`

(And I don't know `pypyodbc` but `pymsql` is working for me.)